# Why is the state of being resident "residence", but the state of being president "presiden-cy"?

Tags: etymology, linguistics, morphology

*Resident* : *Residence* seems like the normal pairing to me. *Residency* isn't exactly unknown ([see here](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=residence,residency&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)), but it's far less common.

But with *President* the derivatives are reversed [and then some](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=presidence,presidency&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). *Presidency* is virtually universal. I'm not sure *Presidence* even qualifies as a word, outside of misspellings for *precedence*.

Why is this?

Comment: You probably want to [read this](http://books.google.com/books?id=TMLkTMkJKLsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=laurie+bauer+productivity&source=bl&ots=GyPqCjjqGu&sig=CmTMXcr6O8jQ8_1qdXQfMR05XaI&hl=en&ei=R-2sTZKLB4PbgQfBn52UDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false). What I'm saying is that, fundamentally, it's a really big question :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Hmmm. I probably want to read several thousand such weighty tomes, and have all the information contained therein instantly accessible to my thoughts. Ideally I'd like all the dope squirted directly into my brain to save the time & trouble of actually doing the reading. In the real world, I was kinda hoping EL&U would save me the trouble (we could all read just one book each, and share what we know).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: FWIW, I attempted to give you an answer. The book link is mostly to show you that this is something people are writing entire books on in an attempt to make sense of it.

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't be so flip. Time permitting I probably will want to read that one. Certainly I appreciate the link.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually, if you really wanted to get a basic feel for the subject matter, you would probably be better off checking out the Aronoff book ([What is Morphology?](http://www.amazon.com/What-Morphology-Fundamentals-Linguistics-Aronoff/dp/0631203192)) and looking at the section on productivity.  Much easier to get through. Bauer's book is probably *way* more in-depth than you would want.

Comment: I did actually do linguistics as part of my degree many moons ago, but I was a callow youth then and I'm a dilettante now. Steven Pinker suits me better than your bookshelf probably would. Thanks even more for the second link though - I should go for that before you start suggesting *Janet and John*!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Hmm. As an American I'd never heard of *Janet and John* until now. I'll check it out — thanks for the suggestion! ;)

Comment: *Janet and John* was a series of children's reading primers in UK, from before I was even born. In the vernacular now it's only ever mentioned in a supercilious context (cf *Mickey Mouse* as applied to technical / mechanical matters). Please don't assume it's representative of our current linguistic level!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Morphology is often "messy" in this way.

**Blocking**

One big reason is probably because there was no need for a semantically distinct word *presidence*.  Though it does not occur 100% of the time, there is a strong effect that is often referred to as [blocking](http://books.google.com/books?id=l4soWecaclsC&lpg=PA211&ots=LpALGd-Y-r&dq=aronoff%20blocking&pg=PA235#v=onepage&q=blocking&f=false) (coined in Aronoff 1976, defined here in Aronoff 2005):

> **Blocking:** the process by which a potential word is prevented from occurring in a language because another form with the same meaning and function already exists.

(The mechanism for blocking depends on your linguistic framework — what is important is that the phenomenon exists, whether you call it "blocking" or something else.)

The words *residence* and *residency* actually mean different things.  That one meaning took the form *residence* while the other took *residency* is almost certainly arbitrary, as the semantic distinction between *-ce* and *-cy* forms can't be generalized across words. But since each word had a semantic niche to fill, each word was able to become established in the lexicon.  (And, with both words established, it might be possible for someone to occasionally substitute the word *residence* for *residency* or vice-versa, for whatever reason.)

As for *presidence*, what might it mean that is distinct from *presidency*?  The fact that there is no answer is probably why such a word does not currently exist.  It could, in theory, come into existence (*existency*? :) some day, should the need arise; there is nothing actually preventing its existence.

**Etymological differences**

The last question that remains is, if only one word is needed then why should it have been *presidency* to begin with and not *presidence*? The answer is probably because of the differing origins of *residence* and *presidency*.

*Residence* entered into English directly from French.  This *-ence* form is common in French; in fact, the word for *presidency* in French is *presidence*.

*Presidency* entered into English by way of post-classical Latin.  So, we anglicized the Latin word *praesidentia* without letting the French get in the middle (as they often do) and throw away a bunch of sounds at the end of the word.  So, *praesidentia* became English *presidencie* and later *presidency*.

Once they became part of the English lexicon, principles like blocking probably kept them organized as they currently are.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. What I still don't get is why it didn't go the other way around (i.e. - *no need for a semantically distinct word* **presidency**). Assuming *residence* was always the more common derivative, why didn't people just start with *presidence*. Could it just be a wish to steer well clear of associations with *precedence*? Or do we have to accept that it's 'just one of those things'?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually, I think it could be any of those reasons.  It is definitely possible that *presidence* was too close to *precedence*, giving *presidency* the edge. However, you just gave me a thought that I will incorporate into the answer.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. And a true asset to this site.