# Is there a rule for -ency and -ence?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Both of frequ**ence** and frequ**ency** seem to be right, but the -ency version may be preferred. I hear more about consis**tency** and converg**ence** more than consist**ence** and converg**ency**.

So, am I right, and is there a rule?

---

NB1: I know it is always sci**ence**, not sci**ency**.

NB2: I'm not a native English speaker. So when I say "I seldom hear xxx", etc., I really mean "to the best of my knowledge", in stead of "xxx is nonsense in English".

Comment: Related: [aberration vs aberrance vs aberrancy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263789). I don't know of any rule

Comment: *Both frequence and frequency* don’t seem to be right at all. *Frequence* is obscure or archaic or both.
Why d’you think this Question belongs here, rather than in English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com)
Did you notice *I seldom hear…* doesn’t at all mean either *to the best of my knowledge* or *… is nonsense*.

Comment: I'm not skilled at English. So I probably cannot get my idea through. If there is something inappropriate, please inform me and I shall rephrase.

Comment: More related questions: [Can someone explain when to use “relevance” and when “relevancy”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230461), [Why is the state of being resident “residence”, but the state of being president “presiden-cy”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21690), [Complacency vs complacence, stagnancy vs stagnance, etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186078)